# Netgear ProSafe S3300 smart switches not stacking

Tags: netgear-prosafe

There are a pair of Netgear S3300-52X switches which are not stacking.

The switches are directly connected by 1m of CAT6 cable between their 10G ports. The switches are both using the same version of the firmware.

Even after a restart, the Netgear switches are not auto-stacking and the switches do not show each other in the stack overview page. There are no other switches and the switches have not previously been stacked.

How can the switches be made to stack?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: on the basis that I wrote the only answer, presumably you are asking to accept it? I'm not sure that any of the upvotes on my answer are people who have genuinely benefitted - they seemed a little too quick - do you have any view on this?

Comment: I am simply trying to get questions with answers to have an accepted answer. If the answers solves the problem, you should accept it. It will remain in the archive for people to search and find the answer. If the answer doesn't help you (unlikely since it is your own answer), then you can leave it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the switches are set to auto-stack when connected, the ports are set to 'ethernet' rather than 'stack' by default, so you have to set the ports to 'stack' mode. To do this:

1. Log onto the switch (default address is
   http://192.168.0.239/base/cheetah_login.html )
2. Go to System->Stacking->Advanced->Stack-port Configuration and set the
   relevant port to ‘Stack’. Note, only the 4 10G ports can be used for
   stacking.
3. Then restart the switches.